# Blackberry Webworks: Feature cannot be found in any extension

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am following the instructions on the "How to Build" section of this site: https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/UIExamples

to build the sample UI example project. I have followed it exactly, but on the last step I get this error message:

[image]

also in the Ripple simulator:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eclipse for Blackberry Webworks; If you are Using Eclipse, then do like this: Directly go to File-->Import-->General-->Existing projects into workspace-->In select root directory-->Browse where the UIExamples are placed and click "finish"; and Build and run;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed an additional extention which is located here for people having the same issue:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/SpinnerControl

After installing that everything went fine.